# JsonConvert SerializeObject not including class property names for a [Serializable] class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I'm serializing a List of objects of a MediaInfo class I have created. When this comes out, I end up with:

```
Object:
    ClassName: "WVO.Media",
    Data: Array():
        0:9
        1: null
        ...
        5: "A3000"
        ...
        8: "Oakland
        ... etc...
```

In short, I'm getting the class property as an integer keyed array instead of with property names. Serialization code is pretty straight forward. First I load the list (List mediaInfos) and then call:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mediaInfos);
```

I can Response.Write things like:

```
Response.Write(mediaInfos[0].MediaTown);
```

... and get the correct output, but I'm confused as to why the property names aren't included in the JSon output. What am I missing?

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using CMS;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.Helpers;
using WVO;

[assembly: RegisterObjectType(typeof(MediaInfo), MediaInfo.OBJECT_TYPE)]

namespace WVO
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MediaInfo : AbstractInfo<MediaInfo>
    {
        #region "Type information"
        public const string OBJECT_TYPE = "wvo.media";

        public static ObjectTypeInfo TYPEINFO = new    ObjectTypeInfo(typeof(MediaInfoProvider), OBJECT_TYPE, "WVO.Media", "MediaID", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
        {
            ModuleName = "wvo",
            TouchCacheDependencies = true,
            DependsOn = new List<ObjectDependency>() 
            {
                new ObjectDependency("MediaMarketID", "wvo.mediamarket",  ObjectDependencyEnum.NotRequired), 
                new ObjectDependency("MediaStateID", "cms.state", ObjectDependencyEnum.NotRequired), 
                new ObjectDependency("MediaTypeID", "wvo.mediatype", ObjectDependencyEnum.NotRequired), 
                new ObjectDependency("MediaSizeID", "wvo.mediasize", ObjectDependencyEnum.NotRequired), 
            },
        };

        #endregion

        #region "Properties"
        [DatabaseField]
        public virtual int MediaID
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetInteger(GetValue("MediaID"), 0);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue("MediaID", value);
            }
        }

        [DatabaseField]
        public virtual string MediaPanel
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("MediaPanel"),    String.Empty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue("MediaPanel", value, String.Empty);
            }
        }

        [DatabaseField]
        public virtual string MediaTown
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("MediaTown"),   String.Empty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue("MediaTown", value, String.Empty);
            }
        }

        ... [several other properties similarly formatted] ...

        #endregion

        #region "Type based properties and methods"
        protected override void DeleteObject()
        {
            MediaInfoProvider.DeleteMediaInfo(this);
        }
        protected override void SetObject()
        {
            MediaInfoProvider.SetMediaInfo(this);
        }
        #endregion

        #region "Constructors"
        public MediaInfo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context, TYPEINFO)
        {
        }

        public MediaInfo()
            : base(TYPEINFO)
        {
        }

        public MediaInfo(DataRow dr)
            : base(TYPEINFO, dr)
        {
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what's `ObjectTypeInfo` looks like?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show the base class `AbstractInfo<MediaInfo>`, but I notice that you have marked your class as `[Serializable]`.  This allows me to make a guess as to what your problem is.

What the `Serializable` attribute means is, "The following .Net type can be serialized by serializing its public and private *fields* -- not its properties."  By default Json.NET ignores this attribute, however it is possible to force it to serialize types with this attribute in this manner by setting [`IgnoreSerializableAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm) on [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) to `false`.  And in fact, asp.net does just this, globally enabling this behavior.  Thus if your `AbstractInfo<T>` base class actually stores its data in some private indexed array, Json.NET will output that private array instead of the public properties.

Now let's try to reproduce the problem with a minimal example.  Consider the following classes:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class AbstractInfo<T>
{
    object[] Data;

    protected AbstractInfo(int tableSize)
    {
        Data = new object[tableSize];
    }

    protected object GetValue(int index)
    {
        return Data[index];
    }

    protected void SetValue(int index, object value)
    {
        Data[index] = value;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MediaInfo : AbstractInfo<MediaInfo>
{
    public MediaInfo() : base(1) { }

    public virtual string MediaPanel
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(0) ?? string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(0, value == "" ? null : value);
        }
    }
}
```

If I serialize this to JSON, the `Data` array appears rather than the property:

```
        var test = new MediaInfo { MediaPanel = "panel" };
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false } };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json); 
        // Prints {"Data":["panel"]}
```

Thus it appears this is almost certainly your problem.

To work around the problem, you can

1. Set `IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true` globally in asp.net.  To do this see [ASP.NET Web API and [Serializable] class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263988/asp-net-web-api-and-serializable-class) or [Setting IgnoreSerializableAttribute Globally in Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125476/setting-ignoreserializableattribute-globally-in-json-net).
2. Mark your class with [`[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptOut)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MemberSerialization.htm):

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
   public class MediaInfo : AbstractInfo<MediaInfo>
   {
   }
   ```