# Using [Serializable] with PetaPoco Entities and WebApi Issues

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

I am trying to use [Serializable] attribute with a PetaPoco Entity so it can be stored in a REDIS Cache.

Adding the [Serializable] attribute to the PetaPoca Entity class allows it to be cached with a REDIS Caching provider but then changes the way the WebAPI serializes the Entity to JSON which breaks.

Is there a way to specify how the  WebAPI serializes the object to JSON?

Examples below, for specifics this is within the DAL2 for DNN and using the https://github.com/davidjrh/dnn.rediscachingprovider REDIS Caching Provider for DNN.

DNN DAL2 / PetaPoco Object:

```
[TableName("sbCurrencyRates")]
//setup the primary key for table
[PrimaryKey("CurrID", AutoIncrement = true)]
//configure caching using PetaPoco
[Cacheable("sbCurrencyRates", CacheItemPriority.Default, 20)]
//scope the objects to the ModuleId of a module on a page (or copy of a module on a page)

[Serializable]
public class CurrRateInfo
{
    public int CurrID { get; set; }
    public string CurrCode { get; set; }
    public double CurrRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

WebApi Controller:

```
public class RatesController : DnnApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetRates()
    {
        CurrRatesController crc = new CurrRatesController();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, crc.Get());
    }        
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HttpGet and HttpPost attribute cannot be used together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a fairly recent version of [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api), then the [Json.NET serializer is being used to serialize your class](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization).  By default Json.NET ignores `[Serializable]`, however it is possible to force it to serialize types with this attribute in the same way that `BinaryFormatter` does (i.e. by serializing their public and private *fields*) by setting [`IgnoreSerializableAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm) on [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) to `false`.  And in fact, asp.net does just this, which globally changes how `[Serializable]` classes are converted to JSON -- as you are seeing.

To prevent this, your options include the following:

1. Set `IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true` globally in asp.net.  To do this see [ASP.NET Web API and [Serializable] class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263988/asp-net-web-api-and-serializable-class) or [Setting IgnoreSerializableAttribute Globally in Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125476/setting-ignoreserializableattribute-globally-in-json-net).
2. Mark your class with [`[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptOut)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MemberSerialization.htm):

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
   public class CurrRateInfo
   {
   }
   ```
3. Annotate your class with [`[DataContract]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes.  These take precedence over `[Serializable]`.

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [DataContract]
   public class CurrRateInfo
   {
       [DataMember]
       public int CurrID { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string CurrCode { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public double CurrRate { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Do this if you don't want a direct dependency on Json.NET from your models, and don't want to change the global behavior of asp.net.