# Serializing a class to JSON generated by xsd.exe using WCF

Tags: c#, json, xml, wcf, serialization

I want to write a RESTful Webservice with WCF which is able to reply in JSON and XML. I have a XML schema from which I generated my classes by using `xsd.exe`. Everthing works fine as long as I request XML, but it fails if I want JSON as response.

The `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter` throws a `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException`. The problem is, what I found out so far, that `xsd.exe` does not generate `DataContract` and `DataMember` Attributes. Is there any solution to this where I do not need to use the `SvcUtil.exe`, because therefore I would need to change my schema..

That is the code where it fails, `JsonDispatchMessageFormatter` is of the type `MultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter`. (Which is the default type anyway)

```
var headers = requestProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] ?? requestProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType];
if (headers != null && headers.Contains("application/json"))
{
    return this.JsonDispatchMessageFormatter.SerializeReply(messageVersion, parameters, result);
}
```

Generated code:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="...")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="...", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Incident {        
    private long incidentIdField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public long IncidentId {
        get {
            return this.incidentIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.incidentIdField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";` before retuning

Comment: Adding `"application/json"` to the outgoing response allows me now to serialize to json, but i have one more Problem. Both XML and JSON serializes the backing fields instead of the properties. I can avoid this for XML using the attribute `XmlSerializerFormat` for my Service Contract, but than I again can't use JSON because it doesn't like this attribute. It suggests my to use `DataContractFormatAttribute`, which will again result in serializing the backing fields..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing private fields rather than public properties in your JSON is that `xsd.exe` has marked your classes with [`[SerializableAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  When this attribute is applied to a type, it signifies that instances of the type can be serialized by serializing *all private and public fields* -- not the properties.

Under the covers, WCF uses [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to serialize to and from JSON.  When this serializer goes to generate a default, implicit data contract for a type without [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it notices the `[Serializable]` attribute and respects it, generating a contract to serialize and deserialize public and private fields.  This is what you are seeing.

What is a bit odd is that [`xsd.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't need to add `[Serializable]` to its generated classes.  `XmlSerializer` *completely ignores this attribute* since it *can only serialize public members*.   (It also completely ignores data contract attributes.  Similarly the data contract serializers all ignore [`XmlSerializer` control attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

Unfortunately, I don't see any [`xsd` command line switches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to disable this attribute.   Thus you're going to do some sort of manual fix:

- Remove `[System.SerializableAttribute()]` from the generated classes.  This should be harmless unless you're using `BinaryFormatter` somewhere; you probably are not.
- Add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes to the generated classes.  (Remember, these are *ignored* by `XmlSerializer` so you're pre-existing XML schema will be unchanged.)
- You might also consider generating contract-appropriate classes with `SvcUtil.exe` then using [automapper](/questions/tagged/automapper) to map your old classes to your new classes.
- Or you might consider switching to a different JSON serializer, such as [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net), where you can [control whether to ignore or respect `[Serializable]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm).  The questions [How to set Json.Net as the default serializer for WCF REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118504/how-to-set-json-net-as-the-default-serializer-for-wcf-rest-service) and [C# WCF REST - How do you use JSON.Net serializer instead of the default DataContractSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003016/c-sharp-wcf-rest-how-do-you-use-json-net-serializer-instead-of-the-default-dat) should get you started.

As an aside, WCF rest may not be the best technology for you if you want precise control over your XML and JSON formatting.  ASP.NET Web API allows for much more precise control of serialization formats by using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net); see [JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) along with [Setting IgnoreSerializableAttribute Globally in Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125476/setting-ignoreserializableattribute-globally-in-json-net) and [.NET WebAPI Serialization k_BackingField Nastiness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334382/net-webapi-serialization-k-backingfield-nastiness).